# OnBackPressed() is not working in activities

Tags: android, onbackpressed

In my project, there are three fragments on the dashboard activity ( the default is selected as a home fragment) with a bottom navigation bar. In the Second fragment(connection fragment), there is a recycler view and when the items are clicked, an activity will be open.

The problem is after opening the activity when I click the back button (I have implemented an image button to go back), it goes to the home fragment, not the connections fragment which has the recycler view.Here is the implemented code.

```
backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               onKeyUp(int,KeyEvent);

            }
        });


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent objEvent) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, objEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        finish();
    }
```

Can someone explain what is the issue.I want to go back to the connection fragment.My bottom navigation bar code as follows,

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener selectedListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.navigation_discover:
                            DiscoverFragment fragment1=new DiscoverFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction ft1=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft1.replace(R.id.content,fragment1 ,"");
                            ft1.commit();
                            return true;

                        case R.id.navigation_places:
                            PlacesFragment fragment2=new PlacesFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction ft2=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft2.replace(R.id.content,fragment2 ,"");
                            ft2.commit();
                            return true;

                        case R.id.navigation_connections:
                            ConnectionFragment fragment3=new ConnectionFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction ft3=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft3.replace(R.id.content,fragment3 ,"");
                            ft3.commit();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.navigation_profile:
                            ProfileFragment fragment4=new ProfileFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction ft4=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft4.replace(R.id.content,fragment4 ,"");
                            ft4.commit();
                            return true;






                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };
```

Comment: remove 
```@Override
    public void onBackPressed() { finish();}```

And can you send the code in your bottom navigation bar Activity

Comment: i have uploaded.Removing the class is not worked

Comment: hey are you calling anything in your onResume() method in your 1st Activity ??

Comment: No.My first activity is the main activity.The fragments are on it.In main activity there is no any onResume() method.

Comment: hey try replacing `ft1.replace(...)` with `ft1.add( .... )` and for all the replace methods invocations while done Fragment transactions , this should work

Comment: not worked@Spiker